# How to Insert Serial to column for Multi rows In Database as per Date

Tags: mysql

How to insert serial to column name s_n [(Image 1 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WraHQ.jpg) as per Date Like
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUkBv.jpg)

I am trying to find a code or a way to add a serial number to several rows in the database as per date at once

Comment: Don't link to images to form your question. It must be asked fully in text; images can at most be used to illustrate your point. As the question stands, I don't understand it. Also, please explain what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

For further questions please use text only, not images.

Your data example

```
create table my_table(
 id int,
 date date ,
 pro_name varchar(10),
 count_item int );

insert into my_table values 
(1,'2024-01-27','PRO-001',10),(2,'2024-01-28','PRO-002',15),
(3,'2024-01-29','PRO-003',20),(4,'2024-01-30','PRO-004',40),
(5,'2024-01-22','PRO-005',30),(6,'2024-01-23','PRO-006',10),
(7,'2024-01-31','PRO-007',50),(8,'2023-12-25','PRO-008',70),
(9,'2023-12-26','PRO-009',30),(10,'2024-01-28','PRO-010',80);
```

Query

```
with cte as (
  select *,
         row_number() over( order by date asc,id asc ) as s_n
  from my_table
   ) select * from cte
order by id asc;
```

Result

```
id  date        pro_name    count_item  s_n
1   2024-01-27  PRO-001         10      5
2   2024-01-28  PRO-002         15      6
3   2024-01-29  PRO-003         20      8
4   2024-01-30  PRO-004         40      9
5   2024-01-22  PRO-005         30      3
6   2024-01-23  PRO-006         10      4
7   2024-01-31  PRO-007         50      10
8   2023-12-25  PRO-008         70      1
9   2023-12-26  PRO-009         30      2
10  2024-01-28  PRO-010         80      7
```

The key part is the `order by date asc,id asc` which sorts the rows by the date first and for same dates sorts by smallest id first.

Note that I used proper date datatype .

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/aUDMIwC3)

---

Now, if s_n is a column which you are trying to update use

```
with To_Update as 
(
   select id,
          date,
          pro_name,
          count_item,
          row_number() over( order by date asc,id asc ) as s_n
   from my_table
)   
update  my_table m 
inner join To_Update t on m.id=t.id
set m.s_n=t.s_n;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejED-j7z)